# Быстрый поиск элемента в отсортированном массиве

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Проблема заключается в поиске элемента **равного** *x* или самого **минимального элемента большего** *x* в отсортированном векторе (массиве). Перебор мне не подходит. Думал использовать бинарный поиск, но как ?

> P.S. Необязательно писать именно про бинарный поиск, все что будет
>   быстрее перебора сойдет. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: бинарный поиск это самое верное, Вы вставьте в вопрос, то что Вы попытались сделать, а дальше я думаю на форуме много людей, которые  смогут "допилить" надфилем алгоритм до хорошего решения

Comment: А что в бинарном смущает?все время arr.length/2..

Comment: В отсортированном - бинарный: разделили наполовину, определили, в какой из них нужное (или ненужное),... Или выгрузить в *Excel* и найти простой формулой (Вы не пишете, что за массив, в какой среде работаете...)

Comment: Бинарный - делим пополам, смотрим, где искомый элемент, и делаем то же самое с нужной половиной. Можно делить не пополам, а пропорционально - например, если у нас 100 элементов, минимальный - 0, максимальный - 1000, ищем 50 - то делим на части от нулевого до пятого, и от пятого до сотого... Вы сформулируйте, что вам нужно - код, описание алгоритсма или что именно?

Comment: Не понимаю, что смущает в бинарном поиске. Он как раз предназначен для решения именно описанной задачи.